Vertices of a polytope
We have a convex (not necessarily linear) problem $f(x)$ with the feasible set being a polytope $P$, where $P=\text{cvxhull}(S)$ is itself a convex hull of a set of dots $S=\{d_1,...,d_{|S|}\}$. We managed to get an optimal solution $x^*\in P$, and that $x^*\notin S$. Furthermore, we're able to express $x^*$ as a convex combination of dots in $S$, wlog say, $x^* = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \alpha_j d_j$, where $n\ll |S|$.
I want to ask: Is any of the $d_j,j=1,...,n$ necessarily attains $\min_{j} f(d_j)$? I think when the objective $f$ is linear the answer is yes. But I wonder if this is still true for convex $f$.

can you clarify "Is any of the $d_j,j=1,...,n$ necessarily attains $\min_{j} f(d_j)$?"

This is not necessarily true. (It is true if $f$ is linear.)
A simple counterexample is $f: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{m} x^2_i$, $S = \{-1,1\}^{m}$ with $\lvert S \rvert = 2^m$, and $x^* = 0$.
